# How to render woff fonts in PhantomJS 2.1+ or headless Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, phantomjs, webfonts, woff

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 on CentOS with the example script `rasterize.js` just to reproduce the screenshot problem, which is to take a screenshot of a simple web-font demo site:

http://castellsonclaret.com/public/external/georgiapro/demo.htm

It should render like so (as taken using the SaaS PhantomJSCloud service):

[image: Correct rendering]

However, with PhantomJS 2.1.1 locally I get

[image: Failed rendering with incorrect colours]

---

First I increased the script timeout to 10s just to be sure that isn't the issue.

Next I thought the css or fonts were blocked somehow from downloading. When I use `tcpflow` (it's like wireshark) before running `phantomjs` scripts I can see that the above web page is downloading the `.woff` fonts. However, they are not being rendered in the screenshot I'm taking.

When I run the following before the phantomjs script

```
tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 | grep -oE '(GET|POST|HEAD) .* HTTP/1.[01]'
```

I can see the fonts are being downloaded. Real console output:

```
GET /public/external/georgiapro/demo.htm HTTP/1.1

GET /t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=4a82c0c9-a48a-4ef5-97ae-de0d7e62c8d0 HTTP/1.1

GET /public/external/georgiapro/Fonts/a5d15255-f5b4-4cca-808f-211ec0f25ac8.woff HTTP/1.1

GET /public/external/georgiapro/Fonts/3859825b-bdc4-47f3-af3d-a2ef42d58cfb.woff HTTP/1.1

... [snip] ...

GET /public/external/georgiapro/Fonts/ab79a7ac-4aaf-4393-896b-feb6610c9528.woff HTTP/1.1
```

---

I then thought that PhantomJS 2.x still doesn't support woff, but 1) it is supposed to be supported (see [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12927)), and 2) the SaaS PhantomJSCloud service can render them fine. Is there something more that is needed to be done to render web fonts?

---

Update: I've confirmed zlib is installed, and compiled PhantomJS 2.1.1 from source, but the results are still the same as above.

---

Update: Chrome has [headless support](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5678767817097216), and that is the reason why on April 13 the maintainer of PhrantomJS has announced he is [stepping down](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE). Eventually we will switch to headless Chrome. Can headless Chrome handle web fonts?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot a experimenting, tweaking, reverse engineering of PhantomJS source code, plus the fact that it is no longer maintained, I switched over to headless Chrome from version 58 with Node.js drivers. It correctly takes screenshots of sites using WOFF fonts.

Here is my setup for anyone interested.

#### Installing Node.js and NPM

```
yum install epel-release
yum install nodejs
node --version # to confirm successful install
yum install npm
# OR, for v8
# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
```

#### Installing Node.js modules

```
npm install chrome-remote-interface --no-bin-links --save
npm install minimist --no-bin-links --save
```

#### Installing Chrome on CentOS

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
yum -y localinstall google-chrome-*
google-chrome --version # to confirm successful install
```

#### Node.js screenshot driver script

Save this script as `screenshot.js`. The source of this script originally came from [here](https://github.com/schnerd/chrome-headless-screenshots/blob/master/index.js). I've modified my version to be more flexible, but to give credit to the author, [schnerd](https://github.com/schnerd/chrome-headless-screenshots), I will reproduce it in its original form:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const file = require('fs');

// CLI Args
const url = argv.url || 'https://www.google.com';
const format = argv.format === 'jpeg' ? 'jpeg' : 'png';
const viewportWidth = argv.viewportWidth || 1440;
const viewportHeight = argv.viewportHeight || 900;
const delay = argv.delay || 0;
const userAgent = argv.userAgent;
const fullPage = argv.full;

// Start the Chrome Debugging Protocol
CDP(async function(client) {
  // Extract used DevTools domains.
  const {DOM, Emulation, Network, Page, Runtime} = client;

  // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
  await Page.enable();
  await DOM.enable();
  await Network.enable();

  // If user agent override was specified, pass to Network domain
  if (userAgent) {
    await Network.setUserAgentOverride({userAgent});
  }

  // Set up viewport resolution, etc.
  const deviceMetrics = {
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight,
    deviceScaleFactor: 0,
    mobile: false,
    fitWindow: false,
  };
  await Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride(deviceMetrics);
  await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight});

  // Navigate to target page
  await Page.navigate({url});

  // Wait for page load event to take screenshot
  Page.loadEventFired(async () => {
    // If the `full` CLI option was passed, we need to measure the height of
    // the rendered page and use Emulation.setVisibleSize
    if (fullPage) {
      const {root: {nodeId: documentNodeId}} = await DOM.getDocument();
      const {nodeId: bodyNodeId} = await DOM.querySelector({
        selector: 'body',
        nodeId: documentNodeId,
      });
      const {model: {height}} = await DOM.getBoxModel({nodeId: bodyNodeId});

      await Emulation.setVisibleSize({width: viewportWidth, height: height});
      // This forceViewport call ensures that content outside the viewport is
      // rendered, otherwise it shows up as grey. Possibly a bug?
      await Emulation.forceViewport({x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1});
    }

    setTimeout(async function() {
      const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({format});
      const buffer = new Buffer(screenshot.data, 'base64');
      file.writeFile('output.png', buffer, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Screenshot saved');
        }
        client.close();
      });
    }, delay);
  });
}).on('error', err => {
  console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
});
```

#### Running Chrome as background process

```
nohup google-chrome --headless --hide-scrollbars --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu &
```

Note: `--disable-gpu` is currently required, see [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)

#### Taking a screenshot

```
node screenshot.js --url="http://castellsonclaret.com/public/external/georgiapro/demo.htm" --outFile="screenshot.png" --format="jpeg" --viewportWidth=1440 --viewportHeight=900 --delay=1000
```

#### Results

WOFF demo:

[image: Screenshot]

Browser capabilities test:

[image: Browser cap]

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use an abstraction so you don't have to deal with the noise that comes from CDP.

I've started a project that just does that (and a few other things as well) https://github.com/joelgriffith/navalia. I'd be more than happy to fix anything you see missing (just throw up an issue!)